# Column equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am preparing now for my linear algebra final exam and come up with the question.
How to prove that two matrices are column-equivalent if and only if they have the same CEF.
I have found a lot of information about row-equivalence ,but what about column.
Is it the same or not?
I know how to prove from the left(If they have the same CEF ->matrices are column equivalent).
I have proved it like that:
Let A and B are both column equivalent to some matrix C. Then,
by symmetry, C is column equivalent to B, and, hence, by transitivity,
A is column equivalent to B.
Is this enough?

Comment: this isn't true unless you require them to have the same reduced column echelon form. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}2 && 0\\1 && 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}4 && 0\\2 && 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are both column equivalent but both are already in CEF

Answer (score 0):

The proof outline for the converse is fine.

If $A$ is column equivalent to $B$, then we have $B=AE_1\cdots E_m$ for some elementary matrices $E_1,\dots,E_m$. Let $C_B$ be the RCEF of $B$ (which is unique, same for $C_A$). Then $C_B = BF_1\cdots F_k$ for some elementary matrices $F_1,\dots,F_k$. Now, $$C_B = A(E_1\cdot E_m\cdot F_1\cdots F_k)$$ which is exactly $C_A$ because $C_B = A(E_1\cdot E_m\cdot F_1\cdots F_k)$ is already in RCEF, and by uniqueness, must be $C_A$.

Comment: Thank you ,but i do not clearly understand your proof.What did you do?You have said that RCEF of matrix A equal to RCEF of matrix B?